# Creating a cron job file

Tags: php, cron

I am currently making single calls to scripts that do the same thing and was wondering if there is a command to make cron run all links in a page?

```
link 1
link 2
link 3
link 4
```

I'm quite new to this but I have searched the net for an answer but maybe I'm not searching for the right terms.

Comment: (1) if youŕe using cronjobs, be sure to don't abuse your own webserver (using other webservers may be OK, but you really don't want to bother your _own_ webserver with something that could be a _cli_ job) (2) If you need to parse links, find a html parser (`DOM` for instance) (3) One does not 'run' links, `GET` requests should have _no side effects_ , use `POST`/`PUT`/`DELETE` et al. for those.

Answer (score 1):

in linux platform you can edit the cron file directly by
`crontab -e` or `sudo crontab -e` and teh cron file you can put a file to run on each line with the interval for itself

see : 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job